# External disk does not work with usb cable

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have an usb cable that I can connect to all my 2,5'' disks using the SATA port. Now I have got a new `WD1600B EVS` that works in a Laptop, but does not run using this cable. Is it possible, that this specific external disk needs more energy and does not run because of that?

Comment: It is possible, try use a shorter cable

Comment: Could you please update with details about the cable you are using (powered or not, etc...) ?

Comment: Yes, WD Blue drives are for “average” performance so it’s possible the drive requires more power then your cable can provide.  However, impossible to say with certainty because you shared nothing about the cable or anything about the other drives